# Update a mongodb document based on its value

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to update some documents in mongodb, basically what I want is to multiply by 2 some property, how can I achieve that?

This is what I tried running:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').update({kId:"house"},
    {$set:
        {
            Count: NumberInt(Count*2) <-- this is illegal
        }
    },{multi:true}
    )
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$mul`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/) operator.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').update(
{kId:"house"},
{$mul:
    {
        Count: 2
    }
},
{multi:true}
)
```